# How to achieve autoplay on mobile (example)

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, browser, slider

So as far as I am aware, video autoplay does not work on mobile.

This is what really confuses me about [this site](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2016/08/05/sports/olympics-gymnast-simone-biles.html?_r=0)

When viewed on mobile the video manages to autoplay. Can anyone figure out how they are achieving this?

I think they are using http://idangero.us/swiper/#.WBvL6OF962w (if that has any relevancy)

Comment: I'm on an iPad so can't rally check but are you sure they aren't gifs rather than videos?

Comment: @Turnip this is the element http://imgur.com/a/cB1nZ. Definitely not a gif as far as i can tell (file size would be in the 20MB+ range if it was anyway)

Comment: Well... it's "sorta" a GIF - that being said, it's a webm, which is a video container (or audio container), but have some similarities to gif in how it behaves in browsers. I dunno if it has anything to do with this site, or the autoplay, but in general, having autoplay on, regardless of device, is a bloody annoyance, ESPECIALLY on mobile. I would reconsider, if I was you. Autoplay is a pita, and shouldn't really be used, unless you have a very good reason. At least remember to set it on mute by default.

Comment: Yep I totally understand the ux problems surrounding autoplaying video. But there are certain use cases where it is required. Especially if your whole story is being told through video (not necessarily audio). But yes your right you have to be very careful with autoplay video. @junkfoodjunkie

I think this might be how they are doing it https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay
That being said. I dont think they are autoplaying it. Just using play() when you get to the slide that it is on (just looked carefully at the html, there is no "autoplay" but there is "muted")